# why do i have this infinite for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am working on this airline program. The program should ask the user how many seats on the plane are sold and then I have this for loop to allow a user to enter a name and a meal choice for each person on the plane.

I have tried reading through some different questions about infinite for loops on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to figure out exactly what is going wrong with my code. I feel like there must be something about for loops that I am not understanding because I thought that it would only go through until your i < someNumber is no longer true.

So when I run this program, say I enter 2 seats I would expect it to go through the loop just twice, but It just keeps going. asking for a name and then a meal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Flyers 
{    
    String name;
    String mealType;

    int economySeats;
    int businessSeats;
    int firstClassSeats;

    int count;

    public Flyers()
    {

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        name = in.next();
        System.out.print("Enter a meal: ");
        mealType = in.next();

        return "Name: " + name + ", Meal " + mealType;
    }

    public void addEconomyFlyers()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of economy seats sold: ");
        economySeats = in.nextInt();

        for(count = 0; count < economySeats; count++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
            name = in.next();
            System.out.print("Enter a meal: ");
            mealType = in.next();

            Flyers newFlyer = new Flyers();
            String seat = newFlyer.toString();
        }

    }
```

Here is my main class if that is helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aviation 
{

    public Aviation()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int option;

       FlightCost newFlight = new FlightCost();
       FlightProfit flight = new FlightProfit();
       Flyers newFlyers = new Flyers();

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter new flight location: ");
       String location = in.next();

       do{
       String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                   + "\n1 (1) Get flight costs."
                   + "\n2 (2) Get flight profits."
                   + "\n3 (3) Enter names/meals."
                   + "\n4 (4) Exit.";

       System.out.println(menu);
       option = in.nextInt();

       }while (option < 0 || option > 4);

       switch(option)
       {
           case 1:
              newFlight.getCost(location);
              break;
           case 2:
              flight.addEconomySeats();
              flight.addBusinessSeats();
              flight.addFirstClassSeats();
              flight.getProfit(location);
              break;
           case 3:
               newFlyers.addEconomyFlyers();
               break;
           case 4:
               System.out.println("Exit");
               break;
           default:
               System.out.println("Error: must select menu option.");
       }      
    }   
}
```

Comment: Add print statements to see what is happening.

Comment: *"why do i have this infinite for loop"* What does your debugger tell you? It's 2014, there's no excuse for not using a debugger.

Comment: its 2014, and I'm just learning any of this, my class is online, my teacher give 0 supplementary material so i'm basically just teaching myself from a book So I have no clue how to use a debugger? and if people are going to down vote they should really give an explanation. i gave info on what it should do, what it is doing, and what I have been trying I'm just looking for some guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove below code from toString()

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    name = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter a meal: ");
    mealType = in.next();
```

You are already reading these from the `for` loop.

Also, your `do-while` loop is all wrong. The condition doesn't make sense. It should be `option > 0 && option <4`

Comment: Perfect thanks. So dumb of me. that was from another attempt at this.

Comment: glad to help. Plz accept the answer if it helped. Thnx

Comment: for some reason every time I have tried to accept an answer and I close out and then go back to it, it doesn't show as being accepted, but I tried it again so hopefully it will save that this time.

Answer (score 0):

As Pat said:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    name = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter a meal: ");
    mealType = in.next();
```

this code in the toString() is obsolete

however the do while does make sense, to me at least, as i see it you want the menu printed out each time the user gives an invalid int, however you are still letting 0 get through although that is not a valid choice, the do while should be:

```
while (option <= 0 || option > 4);
```

or

```
while (option < 1 || option > 4);
```

Another quirk in your code:

```
System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
name = in.next();
System.out.print("Enter a meal: ");
mealType = in.next();

Flyers newFlyer = new Flyers();
String seat = newFlyer.toString();
```

you create a new instance of the class you have just modified and call toString() on, even though you have not populated that class with data, so the toString method as it would be after the edit pat suggested will return "Name:  Meal "

As i see your code is a work in progress, try adding more System.out.print on various variables for debugging purpose or use a debugger, though i know using debugger when learning can be difficult, it sure was for me. Also remember that every time you create a new instance ex:

```
Flyers newFlyer = new Flyers();
```

it has only the data that is either set by default or set in your constructor ex:

```
public Flyers()
{

}
```

I hope what i wrote was helpful, have a nice day and keep at it.